# Pre-requisites for installing IBM InfoSphere BigInsights

Tags: bigdata, biginsights

Pre-requisites for installing IBM InfoSphere BigInsights Quick Start Edition are:

-The root user must have passwordless ssh access to all machines in the cluster.

-The installation administrator user account (admin) must have passwordless ssh access to all nodes.

I only have one ROOT account in my LINUX OS and i'm trying to install it with single node with root user.
How to meet the above two requirements for just the root user in my system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you install single node environment, there is no need to set up SSH keys to get passwordless access to any other machine. You can basically use your root account to install BigInsights on your server.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my understanding to this question. Biginsights is already a bundled system on, what I believe, Red Hat linux enterprise edition. It contains all the necessary linux components and other hadoop ecosystem components. Based on my personal experience, you may choose to use VMware Image to run Biginsights.In such a way, you are promted with two credentials:

- root/password
- biadmin/biadmin